# How can I replace single digit numbers within a string without affecting 2 digit numbers in that string

Tags: javascript

I'm working to update this function which currently takes the content and replaces any instance of the target with the substitute.

```
var content = textArea.value; //should be in string form
var target = targetTextArea.value;
var substitute = substituteTextArea.value;

var expression = new RegExp(target, "g"); //In order to do a global replace(replace more than once) we have to use a regex

content = content.replace(expression, substitute);

textArea.value = content.split(",");
```

This code somewhat works... given the input "12,34,23,13,22,1,17" and told to replace "1" with "99" the output would be  "992,34,23,993,22,99,997" when it should be "12,34,23,13,22,99,17". The replace should only be performed when the substitute is equal to the number, not a substring of the number.

I dont understand the comment about the regex needed to do a global replace, I'm not sure if that's a clue?

It's also worth mentioning that I'm dealing with a string separated by either commas or spaces.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you looking for something like this: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lz9jkjcm/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this if regex is not a requirement

```
var str = "12,34,23,13,22,1,17";
var strArray = str.split(",");

for(var item in strArray)
{
    if(strArray[item] === "1")
    {
        strArray[item] = "99"
    }
}
var finalStr = strArray.join()
```

finalStr will be `"12,34,23,13,22,99,17"`

Comment: I only feel a little silly for not figuring this out. Your === reminded me that I'd been comparing everything with an integer value not a string. 

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
    var string1 = "12,34,23,13,22,1,17";
    var pattern = /1[^\d]/g;
    // or pattern = new RegExp(target+'[^\\d]', 'g');
    var value = substitute+",";//Replace comma with space if u uses space in between
    string1 = string1.replace(pattern, value);
    console.log(string1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
target = target.replace(/,1,/g, ',99,');
```

- [Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: When you say: "a string separated by either commas or spaces"
Do you mean either a string with all commas, or a string with all spaces?
Or do you have 1 string with both commas and spaces?

---

My answer has no regex, nothing fancy ...
But it looks like you haven't got an answer that works yet

```
<div id="log"></div>
<script>
var myString =  "12,34,23,13,22,1,17";
var myString2 = "12 34 23 13 22 1 17";

document.getElementById('log').innerHTML += '<br/>with commas: ' + replaceItem(myString, 1, 99);
document.getElementById('log').innerHTML += '<br/>with spaces: ' + replaceItem(myString2, 1, 99);

function replaceItem(string, needle, replace_by) {
  var deliminator = ',';
  // split the string into an array of items
  var items = string.split(',');
    // >> I'm dealing with a string separated by either commas or spaces
  // so if split had no effect (no commas found), we try again with spaces
  if(! (items.length > 1)) {
    deliminator = ' ';
    items = string.split(' ');
  }
  for(var i=0; i<items.length; i++) {
    if(items[i] == needle) {
      items[i] = replace_by;
    }
  }
  return items.join(deliminator);
}
</script>
```