# Unable to replace some values in regex

Tags: regex

This is my input:

```
0,0,0,1
1,023,1230,1,0
,1,0,01-09-2018,1,
```

I want to replace 0s and 1s whose length is 1. Rest of them will be as it is.

I already tried with javascript code i.e. split all the strings with "," as delimiter. Then, checking for strings with length 1 and replacing them as per logic. But that's a tedious method which consumes a lot of time.
I want a Regex that can do the replacements in entire input.

I have already tried with this regex: `((0|1)(?<=,))|((0|1)(?=,))`. But the output is wrong

Output will be such:

```
N,N,N,Y
Y,023,1230,Y,N
,Y,N,01-09-2018,Y,
```

Comment: Which programming language are you using?

Comment: I think you need `(?<![^,])1(?![^,])` and `(?<![^,])0(?![^,])` to replace with the values of your choice. But https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38567525/how-can-i-replace-single-digit-numbers-within-a-string-without-affecting-2-digit shows the way you tried and it is not that "tedious".

Comment: Hi Wiktor,Thanks for the regex. Its working perfectly!

Comment: Can you please explain your regex @WiktorStribiżew

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following regexps with comma word boundaries:

```
(?<![^,])1(?![^,])
(?<![^,])0(?![^,])
```

Replace with the appropriate substring.

They match `1` or `0` only when enclosed with commas or start/end of string positions.

- `(?<![^,])` - a negative lookbehind that matches a position not immediately preceded with a char other than `,`
- `(?![^,])` - a negative lookahead that matches a position not immediately followed with a char other than `,`.